# How to save an array in method submit using reactjs and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, local-storage

I have a problem with code below:

```
type Formdata{
   title: string
   cant: number
   description
}
// I replace this code to the another code any[], but not
// resolving the problem
// const [sendData, SetsendData] = React.useState<Formdata[]>([])    
const [sendData, SetsendData] = React.useState<any[]>([]) //MYBE PROBLEM HERE
//
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(({title, cant, description})=>{
   let data_send = {
       title: title,
       cant: cant,
       description: description
   }
   // PROBLEM HERE THE FIRST CLICK
   // BUT THE SENCOND CLICK WORKING
   SetsendData(prev=>[...prev, data_send]) // MYBE PROBLEM HERE
   // first click, display undefined
   console.log(sendData)
   //
   window.localStorage.setItem("formreward", JSON.stringify(sendData))
   // in the localStorage save data like this
   // 0: {title: "title one", cant:37, description: "description"}
   // 1: {title: "title two", cant:37, description: "description2"} 
})

return(
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="title" />
      <input type="number" name="cant" />
      <input type="text" name="description" />
       <button>save</button>
    </form>
)
```

the problem is when the first time click, don't save anything, and the console log, display undefined, but the second click does right save data, and this is a problem, because when refresh the page, and try to save data, delete all data in the localStorage. example below:

```
// FIRST CLICK DOESN'T SAVE ANYTHING
[]
// SECOND CLICK WITHOUT REFRESH PAGE
[0: {title: "title one", cant:37, description: "description"}]
// ANOTHER CLICK WITHOUT REFRESH PAGE
[
  0: {title: "title one", cant:37, description: "description"}
  1: {title: "title Two", cant:44, description: "description2"}
]
// WORKING WELL
//
// BUT, WHEN THE REFRESH PAGE AND THE FIRST CLICK 
// DELETE ALL DATA SAVED
[]
```

please would you tell me why happened that and how to fix it, please help me.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is react's update state function are async. given that, when you try to setItem to your localStorage your `sendData` is not updated yet. you may want to use `useEffect` to listen to `senData` state changes and trigger `setItem` accordingly, like:

```
useEffect(() => 
  window.localStorage.setItem("formreward", JSON.stringify(sendData)),
  [sendData])
```

that way, on sendData state updates your localStorage will set it properly.

another approach would to set your next state into a variable before calling update state:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(({title, cant, description})=>{
   let data_send = {
       title: title,
       cant: cant,
       description: description
   }

   const nextState = [...sendData, data_send]
   SetsendData(nextState)
   window.localStorage.setItem("formreward", JSON.stringify(nextState))
})
```

Comment: thanks, buzatto but the "nextState" resolve my problem, and the useEffect I use to load data from localStorage.